# Duas duvidas sobre tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tenho duas dúvidas sobre a GUI Tkinter. A primeira é: como faço para quando o texto de um label for maior que o tamanho do label, o texto ao invés de ficar faltando, continue na próxima linha. A segunda seria como fazer para que textos de uma label que possuem "\n" fiquem alinhados à esquerda, consigo fazer apenas com que o primeiro item fique, os demais ficam centralizados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "Message" ao invés de Label que os dois problemas serão resolvidos de uma só vez.

```
texto = Message(root, text="Bom dia!")
texto.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

para aumentar a fonte de qualquer widget basta importar o modulo tkinter.font
depois instanciar a classe Font com o keywordargument size=20 ,depois basta em qualquer widget na opção font colocar a instância de Font. veja o exemplo:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font
root=tkinter.App()
fonte=tkinter.font.Font(size=20)

butao=tkinter.Button(root,text=ok, font=fonte)
butao.pack()

root.mainloop()
```